# How to remove category from wordpress url?

Tags: categories, permalinks, htaccess

I am new to wordpress so i am facing a problem in removing /category/ from wordpress URL

```
http://domain/category/category-name
```

So i would like to know how to remove /category/ from the url. I have tried various solutions like

```
Go to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: /%category%/%postname%/
Next set your Category Base to /
```

But even after doing this i am not able to remove the /category/ from the URL.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: From what I'm seeing on the Codex, you can change the tag/category pre-fix it puts in the url, but they cannot be removed, or at least not without re-writes and some hacky methods that may go against the natural flow of WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks You can try the plugins suggested or see if this article helps if you go the re-write route: http://www.paulund.co.uk/rewrite-urls-wordpress and http://www.wpexplorer.com/the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for that called WP No Category Base. As the name suggests this plugin will completely remove the mandatory 'Category Base' from your category permalinks ( e.g. myblog.com/category/my-category/ to myblog.com/my-category/ ).

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date alternative: [**Remove Category URL**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend one of these two plugins to get the job done

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/fv-top-level-cats/, or
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

Wordpress SEO has the abillity to remove the `/category/` base and many other valuable features.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found this handy solution which you can use **without plugin**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27569173/851045

```
function fix_slash( $string, $type ) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  if ( $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes == false ) {
    if ( $type != 'single' && $type != 'category' )
      return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'single' && ( strpos( $string, '.html/' ) !== false ) )
      return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) ){
      $aa_g = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
      return trailingslashit( $aa_g );
    }
    if ( $type == 'category' )
      return trailingslashit( $string );
  }
  return $string;
}

add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'fix_slash', 55, 2 );
```

Comment: The above doesn't work for **sub-categories**, though... eg. `www.site.com/main-category/sub-category/`. Returned a 404 error page

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **[CS Remove Category Base](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cs-remove-category-base/)** plugin to get the job done.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cs-remove-category-base/

You can undoubtedly remove /category/ slug from your page WordPress URLs using this plugin.

I hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

Select Custom Structure in permalinks and add `/%category%/%postname%/` after your domain. Adding "/" to the category base doesn't work, you have to add a period/dot.

I wrote a tutorial for this here: [remove category from URL tutorial](http://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/)

Comment: You should add important info inside your answer and **not** a link to where someone might find the relative info :-)

Comment: This does not work for pagination in version 4.6.1