# Change the full slug for a specific category?

Tags: categories, urls, slug

I have multiples categories on my post:

- `/category/blog`
- `/category/sports`
- …And so on.

I also have `/category/news`
I'd like to change this category url to simply have `/news` without the `/category`.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution which is posted for same question.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174508/64614

Hope this will help